# Workflow in place of Auto Response

Tags: workflow, case-auto-response

This may be very vague question, but I have a small doubt on Case Auto-Response rule.

Can I achieve the same scenario of Auto Response Rule with Workflow on Case Object.I kept think about this, but my only difficulty in understanding is how we can track the case sender email address to track and send it to the correct case id.

Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are necessarily looking for this help article -- [Differences Between Auto-Response Rules and Workflow Email Alerts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rules_differences_auto_workflow.htm&type=5) which states:

> Auto-response rules and workflow email alerts provide similar functionality

However, the main difference between the approaches is the use case for which they are *designed for*. You can use either of one depending on your use case.

While using Auto-Response Rules, you target the email to be sent to the Contact who sent the email and created the record. Whereas with Workflow Rule, you can send a notification to any of the contacts you choose.

The help article has a good table which will help you to understand the approaches in detail.